# Saving file to tmp directory when iphone/ipad storage is full

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

Let's say an app downloads images from web while the user is browsing the app. Let's assume there are virtually unlimited images and a new image is downloaded whenever the user demands one. These images are saved to tmp directory for caching purpose. Once the user closes the app, all the images downloaded are deleted by the app.

Now, as there are unlimited images, what will happen if the user requests next image, the storage is full and the app attempts to save the image to the tmp directory?

**Will the previous images be deleted by the iOS automatically to provide the space required for the new images?** 
OR
**Will the iOS start cleaning tmp directory associated with other apps?**(If yes, what happens when the storage is full again and such cleaning has already taken place for all the other apps?)
OR
**Will the app crash?**

Comment: I guess it will start cleaning the `tmp` folders of other apps. But if you have iphone then you can test this.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore thanks for your help Inder, i was expecting some protocol that iOS follows documented some where but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

If you try and save a image to disk and the disk is full then NSData's

```
- (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)aURL
           options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask
             error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

Will return `NO` and an error object will be assigned to the `errorPtr` passed into the method. This error will have a `NSFileWriteOutOfSpaceError`. This error is very exceptional, and by the time you get it it's safe to say the system will have already notified the user that he is running out of disk space.

Having said that, a lot can be said about cleaning after yourself. If you're not going to use a saved image resource anymore then delete it from the file-system.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[tmp/](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

> Use this directory to write temporary files that do not need to persist between launches of your app. Your app should remove files from this directory when they are no longer needed; however, the system may purge this directory when your app is not running.
>   The contents of this directory are not backed up by iTunes.

That's the only thing documented. From this I can infer that it won't purge you `tmp` if your app is running,but it can purge the `tmp` of other apps which are not running

Comment: That seems perfectly fine. We can't predict, though, what may happen in case the tmp directory of other apps are purged, but the storage is full again.

Comment: That all we got from official docs, but if you really want to know then you've to full your iphone and then test this case, and then probably you can answer your question very well. It's interesting to know what will happen, either you can wait for the answer or you can get it yourself. Try it and post the results :)

Answer (score 0):

As @InderKumarRathore says, the docs imply that the system will not delete files from your temp directory when your app is running. The docs also don't promise that the system will delete contents from other apps' temp directories to make space for you.

I would suggest coding defensively: Keep track of the oldest/least recently used files in your temp directory and delete them yourself. Preflight file saves to make sure there is enough space, and display a message to the user if there isn't enough space to save the file(s).